# Airodump on wireless interface error

Tags: aircrack-ng

I'm unable to airodump on my `wlo1` interface.

To set things up, first I set `wlo1` to monitoring mode:

```
sudo ifconfig wlo1 down
sudo iwconfig wlo1 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
```

After running `netstat -i`

[image]

Then I run

`sudo airmon-ng check wlo1`

and kill all shown processes until none remain.

Then I want to run airodump:

`sudo airodump-ng wlo1`

and I get the error:

```
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlo1 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.
```

So I run:

`sudo airmon-ng start wlo1`

and the ouput is:

```
Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlo1        Intel AC    iwlwifi - [phy0]
                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

Now `sudo airodump-ng wlo1` returns the same error.

When running:

`sudo airodump-ng mon0`

there is no network shown.

A few days ago I managed to run airodump fine on `wlo1` and see the reachable networks. Back then `netstat -i` also showed an `M` flag on `wlo1`. Now it seems I have gone through the same steps as before but with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That looks like ubuntu, which makes it a question for U&L or even askubuntu.  Nevertheless, ubuntu has NetworkManager enabled by default, and the NetworkManager daemon will overwrite and config you make through `iwconfig`.

Comment: How about if you start it all over again and try `airmon-ng` , `airmon-ng check` , `airmon-ng check kill` , `airmon-ng start wlo1` and then `airodump-ng mon0`

Answer (score 0):

Some systems after install aircrack-ng suite have not only airmon-ng, they have airmon-zc. Check if is your case, it depends of the aircrack version. It's suppossed that `airmon-zc` (Zero Chaos) is more advanced.

Airmon-zc has the same behavior on cards that airmon-ng has in systems which only have airmon-ng, I mean it changes the mode of the card but not duplicate it. An example of what I say:

- System on which airmon-zc doesn't exist:
  After `airmon-ng start wlan0` you'll get only one interface in monitor mode called `mon0`.
- System on which there are both, airmon-ng and airmon-zc:
  After `airmon-ng start wlan0` you'll get two interfaces. First `wlan0` in managed mode and other called `mon0` which will be in monitor mode. If you execute `airmon-zc start wlan0` you'll get only one interface in monitor mode called `wlan0mon`.

Test your systems and use `airmon-zc` instead if you have it available. To use intentionally `airmon-ng` on systems which have `airmon-zc` is useful to perform different tasks with only one card... for example you can create an AP with hostpad (managed required) and perform a DoS attack (monitor required)... this is used in some Evil Twin attack scripts.

Regarding the NetworkManager... Until version 1.0.12 NetworkManager is not able to change the mode without disrupting your network connection. If you have a lower version than 1.0.12 you'll need to launch not only the airmon check command... you can launch airmon check kill to kill directly the conflicting processes before the airmon start. But if you have NetworkManager 1.0.12 or higher, you don't need to kill any process, no airmon check kill needed. NetworkManager can manage the mode change without problems and you will not lose your internet connection with the change.

Hope this helps.